# Generar Documento en Excel

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excel, datagridview

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en windows form y funciona muy bien cuando doy click en un boton y me genera un documento excel con todos los datos de mi datagridview pero por alguna razon me lo genera en formato de 97-03 siendo que el Excel de mi computadora es del 2013 cual puede ser la razon

```
//Metodo de excel
    private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabaj
            frmEspera espera = new frmEspera();
            espera.Show();
            espera.progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            espera.progressBar1.Maximum = grd.Rows.Count;
            espera.progressBar1.Value = 0;
            espera.lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(grd.Rows.Count);


            for (int i = 0; i <= grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++) 
            {
                int j = 0;
                espera.progressBar1.Value = (i + 1);
                espera.lblCargando.Text = Convert.ToString(i+1);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell celda in grd.Rows[i].Cells)
                {
                    if ((grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Id") == (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "tipoPriority") == (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Seleccionar"))
                    {
                        if (celda.Value != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = celda.Value?.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = null;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }


            }
             libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);

            aplicacion.Quit();
            //  Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;//cambia el tipo de cursor al tipo wait
            //  Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;//restaura el tipo de cursor de defecto

            espera.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: intenta guardarlo  como , excelWorkbook.SaveAs(fichero.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);

Comment: no me funciono amigo,al contrario salio movida @MiguelZarate

Comment: Ya verificaste la versión del ensamblado Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel que tienes como referencia en tu proyecto?